# How to handle chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived event using declarativeNetRequest API in Chrome MV3 extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Currently in my extension (version MV2) I am using `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` to modify response headers for a particular condition. And it is a blocking request. I read I should use `declarativeNetRequest` in MV3 version of extension. But I could not find the alternative for `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` in developer.chrome.com/docs. Any idea/suggestion to implement this scenario in MV3 extension?

Comment: It depends on what exactly your code was doing. There may be no alternative in MV3.

Answer (score 0):

you could remove headers from any web request in MV2 using this code in bg

```html
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function (details) {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i) {
            var detial = details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase();
            if (detial == 'x-frame-options' || detial == "script-src-elem" || detial == "script-src") {
                details.responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
                return {
                    responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
                };
            }
        }
    }, {
    urls: ['*://*/*'],
}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

but it depends on blocking thats been removed.

***Warning:***
**Problem with Google's documentation is its still the old one, it doesn't tell if some api is removed/not working in MV3 or not. you just have to write code and then find out if that api still works.**